# oracle query failed with SQL error code 185

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert rows into a table. I m using oracle database. The query looks as follows:

```
INSERT INTO bv_chglogentry
SELECT DISTINCT account_coid,
                To_timestamp('2018-02-01-16.04.22.428161',
                'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SSXFF'),
                1,
                'HP15004',
                '~HP15004',
                ' ',
                ' ',
                Hextoraw('00257EAB')
                || Hextoraw('0001517F0804011B'),
                Hextoraw('0000000F07650368'),
                ' ',
                0,
                ' ',
                Trunc(To_number(To_char(To_date('2015-05-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'J'
                                ))),
                134480155,
                86399,
                124060520
FROM   inputaccounts;
```

The structure of the tables looks as follows;

```
BV_CHGLOGENTRY
---------------
COID_              NOT NULL CHAR(26 CHAR) 
TIMESTAMP_         NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(9)  
PRODUCT_ID         NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
ADMIN_UNIT_ID      NOT NULL CHAR(8 CHAR)  
OPERATOR_ID        NOT NULL CHAR(10 CHAR) 
OVER_ADMIN_UNIT_ID NOT NULL CHAR(8 CHAR)  
OVER_OPERATOR_ID   NOT NULL CHAR(10 CHAR) 
CHANGE_DATE        NOT NULL RAW(12 BYTE)  
DESCRIPTION_       NOT NULL RAW(220 BYTE) 
BUSINESS_EVENT_ID  NOT NULL CHAR(32 CHAR) 
OWNER_TYPE         NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
OWNER_ID           NOT NULL CHAR(26 CHAR) 
DATE_              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
ZONE_              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
TIME_              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    
CHG_LOG_TYPE       NOT NULL NUMBER(10)    

INPUTACCOUNTS
--------------
ACCOUNT_COID NOT NULL CHAR(26) 
TXN_ID       NOT NULL CHAR(26)
```

there is a column DATE_ which is of NUMBER type. I m having problem with inserting proper data in that column.  The number of columns i'm inserting is 16 which is correct in BV_CHGLOGENTRY.   Can you please let me know what might be the problem with the above query.

Comment: I built your tables and ran your insert in LiveSQL. It created rows in BV_CHGLOGENTRY as expected. [Find the script here (free OTN account required)](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f72b7ac3nq9d0xgelt3y3hmjo). We can only help solve your problem if you post a test case which reproduces it.

Comment: Also, error code `185` is not a valid Oracle error. So you need to post the actual error and error message you get. Or explain what client you're using to execute your SQL.

Comment: @APC . . . If you put your comments in an answer, I for one will upvote it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - thanks for the offer but I would flag it as Not An Answer if somebody else did that :D

Comment: @APC One thing i have observed is, if i randomly hardcode with some value say 1234 in the DATE_ column while insertinginstead of Trunc(To_number(To_char(To_date('2015-05-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'J'
                                ))),  the query works fine without any error.  The actual error which i see is "the query failed with sql error code 185".  Is there any problem with the statement since it works fine with hardcoding.

Comment: Please re-read my comments. I was able to run your code in LiveSQL (Oracle 12c worksheet). So there is **nothing intrinsically wrong** with your statement. And `185` is not an Oracle error. Clue: Oracle errors look like this, `ORA-00001` . So whatever it is you're seeing it's generated by your client app or whatever you're using to run the statement.

Comment: I realise this isn't part of your question, but surely `' '` is not a valid value in business terms for any of the four columns you have used it for. Also why are there `char` columns?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson  But as i said if i hardcode the value say 1234 in DATE_column instead of Trunc(To_number(To_char(To_date('2015-05-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'J' ))),  its working without any problem, even with ' ' for the four columns. So i m looking for the exact root cause for the problem with that statement.

Comment: @SatyanveshD yes but like everyone else it works fine for me, although `to_number(to_char(date '2015-05-02','J'))` is a shorter way to write the same thing, and we don't know what error 185 means (there is no `ORA-00185`). I was just commenting on a couple of other things that looked wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are getting in the date column, after doing insert is not incorrect. It's just converted into **Julian calendar** format. Because you are converting the date into Julian calendar in your `select` query i.e:

Trunc(To_number(To_char(To_date('2015-05-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), '**J**')))

The value that you are getting the date column is correct **i.e** (2457145).

**To avoid this**, you can use **replace()** function in your `SELECT` query where you are doing `Trunc(To_number(To_char(To_date('2015-05-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'J')))`to get readable date in number format.

***Sample query***:

```
select to_number(replace('2015-08-02', '-')) from dual;
```

**Output**: 20150802

Comment: If it's correct, why replace anything? The date literal amounts to `date '2015-05-02'` anyway, so what is the change exactly?

Comment: We need to use replace () function because, if you see his question, he is inserting the date value into number data type column.
The given Sql, that he is using is correct, but after conversion , it got converted into Julian calendar date. i.e not proper understandable.
So the change is:
replace the 'Trunc(To_number(To_char(To_date('2015-05-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'J' )))'
with 'to_number(replace('2015-08-02', '-'))' in the SELET query, to get readable format

Comment: @DHARMINDER Thanks for your reply. But if we use 'to_number(replace('2015-08-02', '-'))' in the select query we just get 20150802. i.e, just the - are replaced to get the value.. But actually i need the julian date value of 2015-08-02 to insert in number type column.  As you said the value looks like 2457145, but not 20150802.  Can you please check the difference and let me know.

Comment: So the query you have given is working fine. It giving the correct date in Julian format. Confused what is your actual question.

Comment: I was actually asking in the previous comment..  I need Julian format date to be stored in the column of number type.  so if the Julian value of 2015-08-02 is 2457145 in Julian format.  I store this in number format...  and what is the correct oracle statement for that instead of the given query Trunc(To_number(To_char(To_date('2015-05-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'J'))) .. hope this gives some idea.

Comment: I have ran same SQL given by you and it is working fine for me, according to your requirement.